# minimum moving parts needed to use VueJS components, preferably in ES5

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-5, vue-loader

I have been around JavaScript for years but only ES5, not ES6.  I have also used VueJS in a single instance by just adding this line:

```
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue.js"></script>
```

But now I'm at the point with VueJS where I want to start using *.vue component files.

Is it possible to do this without using such tools as WebPack etc.?  I really want to avoid having one set of files I write code in, a build process, and another set of files I serve to the user.

Said (hopefully correctly) another way, is there an ES5 version of vue-loader which would work?

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader? Found it here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/in-browser-single-file-components/17147/12

Comment: Out of interest I think you can achieve this with Vue 'render functions'.

Answer (score 0):

No. This will not be happening, as far as I'm aware. To use .vue files, you need a build process.